# What is the proof of Bohr's quantisation rule?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, history, orbitals, semiclassical

In his atomic model, Niels Bohr proposed that electrons can be present only in those orbits where their angular momenta is an integral multiple of $\frac{h}{2π}$. That is

$mvr=\frac{nh}{2π}$, where $n=1,2,3,...$

But how did Bohr get this expression? I know that later de Broglie derived this equation by assuming that electrons were actually standing waves. But how did Bohr get this expression. How did he derive it? There is literally no proof of this equation in my book. I am so confused. Can someone provide me the proof of this equation. Please help.

Comment: I was a postulate of  Bohr or in other words a guess

Comment: Here you go: [Revisiting Bohr’s quantization hypothesis for the atomic orbitals] https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0608102

Comment: *What is the proof?* There isn’t one. You are confused about the nature of theories/models in physics. One cannot mathematically prove their basic assumptions. The only “proof” of their postulates is if the model works experimentally by making correct predictions. Then the assumptions were useful (but not necessarily true) ones.

Comment: My guess regarding why Bohr tried this assumption: He probably knew that for circular orbits under an inverse-square force one has $E\propto 1/L^2$. So if he quantized the angular momentum he could get the [Rydberg formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_formula).

Comment: *proof* according to which axioms? in which theoretical framework do you want a proof? what are the givens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How did Bohr come up with the figure $n\hbar$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/284600/)

Comment: He made the rule based on observation. In such a way they were "proofed".